# The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, int) is undefined Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm getting this error message while using WebDriverWait.

It throws this error message:

> The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, int) is undefined

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("above-expath")));
    element.click();
```

What should i do instead? is it deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofSeconds-long-) instead.

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Comment: Hey!, thank you. Why it is happening?

Comment: @programming_amazing The constructor `WebDriverWait(WebDriver, long)` was deprecated.